# Getting 4.2V regulated voltage

Tags: linear-regulator

There are not too much 4.2V linear voltage regulators on sale. Usually there are adjustable types. I need SOT223 package type fixed one. Microchip's MIC5209 supplies 4.2V but very expensive compared to its equivalents like 1117 type regulators.
My question is: What happen if I feed the 1117 type 5V fixed regulator with 5.1V supply input?
Can it give a **regulated output** or **not work**? My load draws about 200-300mA and about 4V output is acceptible.
I've read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346785/1117-regulator-input-voltage#:%7E:text=Vout%20will%20likely%20be%20approximately,1.3%3B%20depending%20on%20output%20current.&text=So%20from%20a%20design%20perspective,a%20clean%205%20V%20out.) Output=Input-Dropout and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109674/zener-diode-as-voltage-regulator) zener diode solution is mentioned. Maybe I can coincide zener to sot223 footprint but i'm not sure its stabilitiy.

Comment: What is your input voltage?

Comment: Are you saying you need a drop-in (pin-for-pin compatible) replacement for the MIC5209?

Comment: Why do you need a fixed regulator anyway? Seems like an artificial constraint. Two resistors are small and cheap and would open the field up to many other types of regulators,  probably with lower prices and/or better performance and more sources.

Comment: Not artificial. The voltage drives Microcontroller and varying voltage always changes the supply of Microcontroller. This results changing of analog output always. For example i set 2v analog output, it always varies between 1.8-2.2V since the power is not regulated.

Comment: One of the important point of my question is: how behave AMS1117 or LD1117 similar fixed type 5V regulators when input voltage is also about 5V. Work&regulate or doesn't work?

Comment: Most fixed linear regulators will simply pass the voltage when it is under the drop out voltage.  Some will shut off.  Check out the datasheet, it will describe the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an uncommon voltage, then an adjustable regulator is the way to do it.
The [LM1117-ADJ](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf?ts=1613665487668&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.de%252F) will work fine with up to 15V input. 
You will also need about 1.25V or more, above your output voltage (with this chip). So your circuit will need about 5.5V input minimum.

Comment: There is no space for resistors in the adjustable type. The PCB is designed for fixed type. This is limiting point for me and why i should do this.

Answer (score 1):

The zener diode approach isn't a great one if your load current is going to vary much, and there's some trickiness that I don't think you want to manage. I would suggest you find a fixed voltage regulator that will meet your needs.

At the risk of turning this into a shopping question...

You've put some restrictions on your choice by saying it must be SOT223. That is a larger package than is popular for a lot of low voltage or battery-powered applications. If it must also be pin-compatible with the Microchip part, you've put on additional restrictions that narrow down your options.

If 4.3V is acceptable, take a look at https://www.ti.com/product/TPS736

If you can accept a different package, your options are a bit wider. For example: https://www.ti.com/product/TLV757P

Those are just two possibilities from TI; there are several companies that make 4.0V or 4.2V fixed-voltage LDO regulators.

Comment: I dont want to manage zener`s tricks as you said.